# Autocorrelation of random walk

Tags: python, autocorrelation, random

I want to analyze the auto-correlation of a received power signal that I captured. Unfortunately, I cannot publish the data but I found the same problem arises for a random walk, that's why I used the random walk in the code snippet below.

The problem is that the progression scales with the number of input samples, i.e., the zero-crossing happens every time at approximately `0.23*len_walk`, no matter what `len_walk` actually is. I'm not sure about the reason, maybe someone can help me interpret.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf

len_walk = 1000
n_walks  = 100

acf_sum = np.zeros(len_walk)

for j in range(n_walks):
  w = [0]
  for i in range(len_walk-1):
    w.append(w[-1] + np.random.normal())

  acf_result = acf(w, nlags=len_walk)
  acf_sum = acf_sum + acf_result

plt.plot(acf_sum/n_walks, label='acf_sum')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
```

Is it that the absolute difference between minimum and maximum value increases (on average) the longer the time is, so samples that have been previously close to uncorrelated look now correlated given more values?

Comment: I think you need to _edit your question_ for clarity and completeness.  That code is just for a random walk, so it doesn't relate much to the text or title.  Please tell us how a power measurement gets involved.  Specifically, tell or show us things about the signal in question.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; how can you know the problem with your actual system has the same solution as for a random walk? If you can say that, it means you have an explicit mathematical signal model, and you should rather describe that than some more-or-less similar signal. I'm also not a fan of the principle "I want your help, but I need to keep it a secret about  what!" If that's the case, pay a consultant to sign an NDA / undergo security clearing. Crowdsourcing knowledge is a 100% one-way street if you're secretive even about your problem, so this damages the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to figure this out from first principles.

Let's start with $x$ our zero-mean, Gaussian, independent, identically distributed noise sequence:
$$
x[n] \sim N(0,\sigma^2_x)
$$
Then our random walk is just the accumulation of these values
\begin{align}
y[n] &= y[n-1] + x[n], \mbox{ for } n \ge 0, x,y = 0 \mbox{ for } n < 0.\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n x[k]
\end{align}
The variance of $y[n]$ is just
\begin{align}
\sigma^2_y &= E\left[ y[n] y[n] \right]\\
&= E\left[ \sum_{k=0}^n (x[k])^2\right] + \mbox{ expectation 0 terms}\\
&= (n+1) \sigma^2_x
\end{align}
We can extend this to look at the covariance of $y$ for $m \ge n \ge 0$
\begin{align}
E[y[n]y[m]] &=  E\left[ \sum_{k=0}^{n} (x[k])^2\right] + \mbox{ expectation 0 terms}\\
&= (n+1) \sigma^2_x
\end{align}
Then the autocorrelation is:
\begin{align}
\rho_y(n,m) &=  \frac{E\left[ y[n] y[m]\right]}{\sqrt{E\left[ y[n]y[n]\right]E\left[ y[m]y[m]\right]}}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{m+1}}
\end{align}

And there's the problem: the **$\color{red}{\bf \mbox{random walk is not a stationary process}}$**.

Because `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf` aims to capture second order statistics as a function of a single lag, this doesn't make sense for the random walk.

For example, the lag of 1:
\begin{align}
\rho(0,1) &= 0.707\ldots\\
\rho(1,2) &= 0.816\ldots\\
\rho(2,3) &= 0.866\ldots\\
&\vdots\\
\rho(100,101) &= 0.995\ldots\\
\end{align}